# How to webscrape PDFs that are hidden under the selection option?

Tags: python, web-scraping, pdf-scraping

I am trying to download >100 pdf from a website using python. However, those pdfs are hidden under the selection option. For example:

- Option 1
- Option 2
- Option 3
  ...

Then, if I choose Option 1, I something lie this:

- Option 1

  - Clickable Link to Info 1 [Clickable link to File 1]
  - Clickable Link to Info 2 [Clickable link to File 2]
  - Clickable Link to Info 3 [Clickable link to File 3]
  - Clickable Link to Info 4 [Clickable link to File 4]
    ...
- Option 2
- Option 3

Once I press on, e.g., "Clickable link to File 1", picture pops up with an option to "View PDF" in top right corner of the pop up. Now how do I download PDFs in a loop for each of the files under Option 1? I am new to webscraping and your help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share URL?

Comment: https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2016/dp-pd/prof/search-recherche/lst/results-resultats.cfm?Lang=E&TABID=1&G=1&Geo1=&Code1=&Geo2=&Code2=&GEOCODE=35&type=0#

Comment: Where are the PDFs on this page?

Comment: Press on [map]. Pop-up will show up. Then, there is an option for PDF in top right corner of pop-up.

Comment: I tried researching already answered similar questions, but they don't seem to be webscraping pdfs given mine website format with multiple dropdown options. Furthermore, once you press View PDF it will take you to a different link which will have the actual PDF link. That's the link of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you can construct PDF Url from the link identifier automatically. For example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2016/dp-pd/prof/search-recherche/lst/results-resultats.cfm?Lang=E&TABID=1&G=1&Geo1=&Code1=&Geo2=&Code2=&GEOCODE=35&type=0"
map_url = "https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/geo/maps-cartes/pdf/{id1}/{id2}.pdf"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for a in soup.select("a[data-dguid]"):
    id_ = a["data-dguid"]
    m = map_url.format(id1=id_[4:9], id2=id_)
    print("{:<60} {}".format(a["data-geoname"], m))
```

Prints:

```
...

Map: Arthur [Population center], Ontario                     https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/geo/maps-cartes/pdf/S0510/2016S05100022.pdf
Map: Atikokan [Population center], Ontario                   https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/geo/maps-cartes/pdf/S0510/2016S05100028.pdf
Map: Attawapiskat 91A [Population center], Ontario           https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/geo/maps-cartes/pdf/S0510/2016S05101497.pdf
Map: Aylmer [Population center], Ontario                     https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/geo/maps-cartes/pdf/S0510/2016S05100030.pdf
Map: Ayr [Population center], Ontario                        https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/geo/maps-cartes/pdf/S0510/2016S05100031.pdf
Map: Azilda [Population center], Ontario                     https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/geo/maps-cartes/pdf/S0510/2016S05101498.pdf
Map: Ballantrae [Population center], Ontario                 https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/geo/maps-cartes/pdf/S0510/2016S05101370.pdf
Map: Barrie [Population center], Ontario                     https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/geo/maps-cartes/pdf/S0510/2016S05100043.pdf
Map: Barry's Bay [Population center], Ontario                https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/geo/maps-cartes/pdf/S0510/2016S05100044.pdf
Map: Bath [Population center], Ontario                       https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/geo/maps-cartes/pdf/S0510/2016S05101403.pdf

...
```

Comment: Hello Andrej, this is amazing! I will take this as a starting point and try to filter out those of interest. I could also then loop through each link to download pfds. Please allow me to get back to you if I have any questions.

Comment: Hello Andrej, another question. Starting from the same master link of Census Canada stated above, how would I go about downloading the CSV files or rather printing out the addresses for the CSV files just like done for the pdfs above? An example of CSV file can be seen here: https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2016/dp-pd/prof/details/page_Download-Telecharger.cfm?Lang=E&Tab=1&Geo1=CSD&Code1=3556033&Geo2=PR&Code2=35&SearchText=Abitibi%2070&SearchType=Begins&SearchPR=01&B1=All&TABID=1&type=0.

Comment: @IsaacA To not clutter the comment section, I'd suggest to open a new question Here on StackOverflow. I'll try to look at it.

Comment: Understood. I will do this shortly. I am going to close this question.

Comment: All done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68181565/how-to-webscrape-the-csv-files-that-are-hidden-behind-the-button