# How to webscrape the CSV files that are hidden behind the button?

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

I am trying to download more than 500 CSV files from the below website using python:

https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2016/dp-pd/prof/search-recherche/lst/results-resultats.cfm?Lang=E&TABID=1&G=1&Geo1=&Code1=&Geo2=&Code2=&GEOCODE=35&type=0#

The issue is that the CSV file is hidden behind several links. For example:

1. Initial link:

https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2016/dp-pd/prof/search-recherche/lst/results-resultats.cfm?Lang=E&TABID=1&G=1&Geo1=&Code1=&Geo2=&Code2=&GEOCODE=35&type=0#

2. Example sublink (around the top, there is a downward arrow download button that needs to be pressed which takes the user to another link):

https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2016/dp-pd/prof/details/page.cfm?Lang=E&Geo1=CSD&Code1=3556033&Geo2=PR&Code2=35&SearchText=Abitibi%2070&SearchType=Begins&SearchPR=01&B1=All&GeoLevel=PR&GeoCode=3556033&TABID=1&type=0

3. Second sublink (What I am interested in is the "Option 1: Download data as displayed in data table" and the File Format is CSV. The CSV button needs to be pressed to download the file):

https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2016/dp-pd/prof/details/page_Download-Telecharger.cfm?Lang=E&Tab=1&Geo1=CSD&Code1=3556033&Geo2=PR&Code2=35&SearchText=Abitibi%2070&SearchType=Begins&SearchPR=01&B1=All&TABID=1&type=0

I am trying to achieve the similar solution as in my previous post. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think I have an idea. Both PDF files and CSV link share unique 7 digit number. I could get list of all of the unique 7 digit numbers of interest which I could use to query/download the CSV files. Let's see how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


main_link = "https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2016/dp-pd/prof/search-recherche/lst/results-resultats.cfm?Lang=E&TABID=1&G=1&Geo1=&Code1=&Geo2=&Code2=&GEOCODE=35&type=0"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(main_link).content, "html.parser")

for a in soup.select('details a[href*="page.cfm"]'):
    link = a["href"]
    link = link.replace(
        "../../details/page.cfm",
        "https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2016/dp-pd/prof/details/download-telecharger/current-actuelle.cfm",
    )
    link += "&FILETYPE=CSV"

    print(a.get_text(strip=True))
    print(link)
    print()
```

Prints:

```
Abitibi 70 (Indian reserve)
https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2016/dp-pd/prof/details/download-telecharger/current-actuelle.cfm?Lang=E&Geo1=CSD&Code1=3556033&Geo2=PR&Code2=35&SearchText=Abitibi%2070&SearchType=Begins&SearchPR=01&B1=All&GeoLevel=PR&GeoCode=3556033&TABID=1&type=0&FILETYPE=CSV

Addington Highlands (Township)
https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2016/dp-pd/prof/details/download-telecharger/current-actuelle.cfm?Lang=E&Geo1=CSD&Code1=3511035&Geo2=PR&Code2=35&SearchText=Addington%20Highlands&SearchType=Begins&SearchPR=01&B1=All&GeoLevel=PR&GeoCode=3511035&TABID=1&type=0&FILETYPE=CSV

Adelaide-Metcalfe (Township)
https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2016/dp-pd/prof/details/download-telecharger/current-actuelle.cfm?Lang=E&Geo1=CSD&Code1=3539047&Geo2=PR&Code2=35&SearchText=Adelaide-Metcalfe&SearchType=Begins&SearchPR=01&B1=All&GeoLevel=PR&GeoCode=3539047&TABID=1&type=0&FILETYPE=CSV

Adjala-Tosorontio (Township)
https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2016/dp-pd/prof/details/download-telecharger/current-actuelle.cfm?Lang=E&Geo1=CSD&Code1=3543003&Geo2=PR&Code2=35&SearchText=Adjala-Tosorontio&SearchType=Begins&SearchPR=01&B1=All&GeoLevel=PR&GeoCode=3543003&TABID=1&type=0&FILETYPE=CSV

Admaston/Bromley (Township)
https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2016/dp-pd/prof/details/download-telecharger/current-actuelle.cfm?Lang=E&Geo1=CSD&Code1=3547043&Geo2=PR&Code2=35&SearchText=Admaston/Bromley&SearchType=Begins&SearchPR=01&B1=All&GeoLevel=PR&GeoCode=3547043&TABID=1&type=0&FILETYPE=CSV

...and so on.
```

Answer (score 0):

The links of all the first sublinks are listed as `<li>` elements. In my opinion, parsing the HTML text of the initial link and storing the first sublinks in a list and then navigating to them using selenium (and downloading the CSVs) would be the way to go.